# Magento2 : getting 404 not found error after setup upgrade

Tags: magento-2.1

My magento2.1 store (production mode) was working properly, but after run setup:upgrade commands frontend console showing 404 error for core js file.

I also executed static content deploy commands but still issue persist.

Please suggest how to resolve this?

**EDIT**

Console showing below errors :

[image]

And in system.log errors are :

```
main.CRITICAL: Directory "/public_html/pub/static/_requirejs/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/secure" cannot be created Warning!mkdir(): Permission denied [] []
main.CRITICAL: Block requirejs-config throws exception and cannot be rendered. [] []
```

Comment: can you please post your error which you get it in Log file?

Comment: Please check my edit question.